# How do I use a WebBrowser to get an element by ID or class attribute?

Tags: html, vb.net

I know that in a WebBrowser you can use `Document.GetElementById` to find an element by its `name` attribute, but I want to search the webpage for an element using the `id` or `class` atributes, how would it be possible to do this in a WebBrowser? I want to make it click on an image tag.

```
<td id="button1-cell"><img src="/static/button1.png" alt="Button 1" id="but1"></td>
```

Also, is it possible to `InvokeMember("click")` on divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetElementById's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) says that it gets an element by ID, not name.  If you want to find an element by name, you can use

```
webBrowser1.Document.All("name")
```

Comment: I don't know why, but for me in Visual Basic it uses it to get an element by its name attribute. If I tried using it to get an id it would throw an error.

Comment: It works fine for me.  I took your example and pasted it into an example HTML page and was able to do this: MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("but1").GetAttribute("src")).  It looks like getElementById is trying to be smart and will use the name if the ID does not exist.  You may want to make sure you are clearing your cache in IE before you test, as I ran into a problem during testing that loaded a cached version of my page.

Comment: But how would it be possible to _click_ the image/button? I tried `MasterBrowser.Document.GetElementById("but1").InvokeMember("click")` but it threw "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"

Comment: That code works perfectly fine for me.  Are you sure the page is fully loaded before you are calling the GetElementById method?